# mpstat on slackware 13.0 shows no utilization

Tags: linux, performance-monitoring, slackware

As the title says, the mpstat command, executed on Slack 13.0 continuously shows *almost* no processor utilization of any sort. In fact none of the output ever seems to change at all. The system is dual processor board with two hyperthreaded P4 Xeons. Any ideas?

```
08:50:06 PM  CPU   %user   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal   %idle    intr/s
08:50:06 PM  all    0.38    0.00    0.03    0.03    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.56   1510.46
08:50:06 PM    0    0.50    0.00    0.05    0.10    0.00    0.01    0.00   99.33     11.90
08:50:06 PM    1    0.32    0.00    0.03    0.01    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.64      0.00
08:50:06 PM    2    0.38    0.00    0.03    0.01    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.58      0.00
08:50:06 PM    3    0.29    0.00    0.02    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.68      0.00
```

This is the only output I can get from the program. No values change ever.

Comment: As a note, TOP works fine.

Comment: As an interesting not both 'top' and 'vmstat 1' seem to display a behaviour which is not dissimilar: the first update both of those programs produce shows no CPU usage. The second update jumps to the appropriate numbers, with, say, loading one virtual core displaying 25% usage. I suppose I could, with a bit of hackery, just capture that output and use it...

Answer (score 2):

Seems to have been a misunderstanding. Mpstat prints avg's since system boot if it is not given any args, the documentation seems to have been a little unclear in its workding. To get one set of current statistics the command mpstat 1 1 can be issued, however it takes one second to return with the proper data.

Comment: Thank you, this was driving me insane. I'm assuming it takes a second to run as it reads the /proc/stat counters, and has to take 2 readings. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017162/how-to-get-total-cpu-usage-in-linux-c